# using facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate the official `Facebook sdk` with my android app.
I am following this link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Everything is fine until I come to the step - exporting the signature for your app 
Here they ask us to run this command :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
```

When I run this I get a huge pattern containing all sorts of characters & symbols
I am confused that which one is my requires `String`.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about it once, [here](http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-facebook-integration.html). 
It also has a sample project.

I think it should solve your issues.
if you're still unsure, revert.

Answer (score 0):

From the [keytool documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html):

> If no file is given, the certificate is output to stdout.

Same thing for [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html): the output goes to standard output.

If you want to save the output in a file, just redirect the output. On most operating systems, this si done with `>`

```
keytool ... | openssl base64 > key.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the complete string you have to use.